# Why is it that ArrayList works with COM Interop, but IList<T> doesn't?

Tags: generics, scripting, com-interop

I've noticed that if I make a .NET component that exposes an ArrayList, then that ArrayList passes through COM Interop and is available in scripted languages such as VBScript.

Generics, such as `IList<T>` do not seem to work.

Why is this and is there any way to make a generic type successfully flow through COM Interop to a scripting engine?

Comment: Because COM doesn't support generics.  
Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862497/c-exposing-class-to-com-generic-collections) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269581/what-are-alternatives-to-generic-collections-for-com-interop) question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generics were added in .NET 2.0 and COM existed before .NET 1.0.
(And was the technology .NET *aimed* to replace.)

COM never had generics, and therefore you cannot expose them.
Neither of COM languages (C++, VB6, Delphi) had generics so you can't expect them to be consumed.
(Well, C++ had templates but they are completely a different beast, and COM only meant *interfaces*.)

Exposing collections as an `ArrayList` is the [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269581/what-are-alternatives-to-generic-collections-for-com-interop) to this problem, you can't work around it.

> **Disclaimer**: I am no expert on COM so the rest of the answer is roughly based on my guesses.

COM never “had” `ArrayList`s, true, but so it never had *any* of the classes in .NET Framework, because it is not a framework itself. However, some of the .NET types get into the exported type libraries, and some don't. What about .NET Framework classes? Well, `ArrayList` is `[ComVisible]`, and `List<T>` isn't.

Why?

COM [works via interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Interfaces), and the Interface Definition Language has no clue about generics and doesn't support them. Languages that support COM, such as VB6 or C++, wouldn't know what to do with the generics.

If there was a way to generate an interface for `List<T>`, it would *not* contain `T` in it so there is essentially no point in trying to expose a generic type. Possible imaginary alternatives to this would be:

- Generating a “specific” version of interface for a generic type, e.g. `IListOfString` for `List<string>`
- Erasing generic type information (much like Java does on compilation) and replacing `T` with `object`.

The first option is not viable because the concrete `T` type may not be known at compilation (read: Reflection), and `List<T>` doesn't have a `[ComVisible]` attribute on it anyway.

The second option is actually sort of possible because you can [provide your own class interface with `IList` and `ICollection` properties](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jul/10/Generics-and-COM-Interop-dont-mix#192110):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get;set;}
    DateTime Entered { get;set;}
    IList NickNamesList { get;}
    ICollection NickNamesCollection { get;}
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IPerson))]
public class Person:IPerson
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public List<string> NickNames
    {
        get { return _NickNames; }
        set { _NickNames = value; }
    }
    private List<string> _NickNames = new List<string>();

    #region IPerson Members
    IList IPerson.NickNamesList
    {
        get { return this.NickNames; }
    }

    ICollection IPerson.NickNamesCollection
    {
        get { return this.NickNames; }
    }
    #endregion
    ....
}
```

This is a workaround and doesn't answer your question though.

I am actually wondering if you could derive your `StringList` class from `List<string>` and mark it as `[ComVisible(true)]`. You may want to check that.

Comment: I can't accept that. Microsoft made ArrayList work (COM never had ArrayLists) - so it must be possible to somehow make other types work. Generics have concrete types at runtime. What is the mechanism that makes an ArrayList work?

Comment: I am no expert on COM but I edited the answer to incorporate some of my guesses.

Comment: Let's assume late binding (IDispatch) and see if that puts a different slant on things. Every .NET type is a concrete type at runtime, so as long as late binding is used from the COM component, it should be able to 'see' the concrete type derived from a generic. Given that COM has its own type system, some conversion is necessary between the .NET types and the COM types. I've been doing some reading today and now I wonder if it might be possible to use a custom marshaller to 'expose' a generic type to COM? My knowledge of COM is really weak though, so I'm really just shooting in the dark.